# Should [UIView endEditing:YES] ever return no?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am having a hell of a time fixing a bug, which currently is only occurring when I run my app on the simulator.  Essentially, I have a `UITextView` that I am trying to send the message `endEditing` to.  If I send the message while the user is editing the textview (forced or otherwise) I get back YES.  If however, the user has not yet begun editing the textview and I send the message `endEditing:YES`, I get back `NO`.  Should this even be possible?  Shouldn't `endEditing:YES` always force the view to end editing?

Additional Details:  I have tried setting the owning class to be the uitextviews delegate, but even then it doesn't look like the `shouldEndEditing` method even gets called.

---

UPDATE: It does not seem that this is normal behavior (that the method should return no if the text field is not currently the first responder).

I created a simple test:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DRAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (assign) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (assign) IBOutlet UIButton *endButton;
@property (assign) IBOutlet UILabel *results;

-(IBAction)tapEndEditingButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

and AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)tapEndEditingButton:(id)sender
{
    BOOL didEndEditing = [self.window endEditing:YES];
    NSString *result = (didEndEditing) ? @"YES" : @"NO";
    _results.text = result;
}
```

Regardless of whether the textfield has focus, and regardless of whether I set the force parameter of endEditing to YES or NO, didEndEditing gets set to YES.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Apple Doc on UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW100)

> ### endEditing:
>
> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
>
> ...
>
> **Return Value**
>
> `YES` if the view resigned the first responder status or `NO` if it did
>   not.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for
>   the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one,
>   it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the *force*
>   parameter is set to `YES`, the text field is never even asked; it is
>   forced to resign.

---

So... When you said:

> *If however, the user has not yet begun editing the textview and I send the message endEditing:YES, I get back NO*

It's perfectly fine because in your scenario, since there is no `firstResponder` to resign, calling `-endEditing:` will return `NO` and doesn't harm the performance (*isn't a bug either, imho*)

---

### To answer the essence of the question:

`[UIView endEditing:YES/NO];` will return `NO` if the specified `UIView` object was not the `firstResponder`.

Example:

```
-(void)testEndEditing
{
    UIButton *btnTest = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnTest setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 130, 320, 44)];
    [btnTest setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [btnTest addTarget:self action:@selector(myEndEditing:) 
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnTest setTitle:@"End Editing" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btnTest];

    UITextField *txtFTest = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [txtFTest setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 30)];
    [txtFTest setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [txtFTest setText:@"textField"];
    [self.view addSubview:txtFTest];

    /*
    globally declare "UITextView *txtVTest;"
     */
    txtVTest = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [txtVTest setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 50)];
    [txtVTest setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [txtVTest setText:@"textView"];
    [self.view addSubview:txtVTest];

    //make UITextField object the firstResponder
    [txtFTest becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

---

```
-(void)myEndEditing:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //test endEditing method on UITextView object
    BOOL isWhat = [txtVTest endEditing:YES];
    NSLog(@"%i",isWhat);
}
```

PS: If neither the `textField` nor the `textView` is the `firstResponder` then it returns `YES` (*dunno why but i'll check*)

Comment: `If the force parameter is set to YES, the text field is never even asked; it is forced to resign`.. yet the method is still returning NO for the OP.

Comment: @JamesWebster : i add content to my answers gradually :P

Comment: Yes. but a simple test shows that this is in fact not what always happens.  I created a simple test application with a textview, a button, and a label.  There is only one action:

    -(void)tapEndEditingButton:(id)sender
    {
        BOOL didEndEditing = [_textView endEditing:YES];
        NSString *result = (didEndEditing) ? @"YES" : @"NO";
        _results.text = result;
    }

No matter what, when I tap that button, the result label reads yes.

Comment: I'm also still (very) confused as to why the behavior is different on the iPad and on the iPad simulator.

Comment: @Plastech : hm... indeed it is. will need to dig a bit into this behavior

Comment: @Plastech : (_don't change a thing_) put a `UITextField`, select it to make it the `firstResponder` and now tap on the button (_you should get `NO`_) ___PS: just identifying cases___

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with it. I don't think the `force` parameter works. If you implement `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` and then invoke `endEditing:YES` and the field is first responder `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` will still be called, just the same as invoking `endEditing:NO`.

Comment: @MurraySagal : actually, both are supposed to work. the YES/NO is just the force paramter. Setting it to `NO` **will** "_ask_" the object to resign itself while `YES` will **not** "ask" and instead immediately & unconditionally resign it. that's about it. refer: [link](http://objdev.com/2013/11/Dismissing-iOS-Keyboard-Self-View-EndEditing)

Comment: @staticVoidMan Except that YES does ask, just like NO. It doesn't work as documented. So I'm wondering if that is related somehow to the issue the OP is having.

Comment: @MurraySagal : i have noticed that setting `force` to `YES` will indeed call `-textViewShouldEndEditing:` **but**... setting it to `NO` will call `-textViewShouldEndEditing:` **twice** (_which is weird either ways_). Maybe there's something more inside (_hm_...)

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yes, I've seen that too. I use a method I call `dejavu` to manage that. And just for clarity, I've only tried this with text fields. Are you seeing this with text views?

Comment: @MurraySagal : yes, for both `textViewShouldEndEditing:` & `-textFieldShouldEndEditing:`. btw... what do you have in your `dejavu` method and in which scenario do you use it? (_just curious_)

Comment: @staticVoidMan It's pretty specific to my particular case but here it is. And I see now that it was `textViewShouldBeginEditing` that was being called twice. Anyway in `textViewShouldBeginEditing` I was pushing a view controller. Because of the double call I call `dejavu` first which returned a bool from this: `return [[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[MyPushedViewController class]];`. If it returned true then I knew I already pushed it so just return.